# Can I prevent exportfs from from breaking ZFS sharenfs exports?

Tags: nfs, zfs, zfsonlinux

I'm using ZFS on Linux as a fileserver running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS.  The ZFS pool shares a number of datasets using it's `sharenfs` property.  Outside of ZFS there are a few additional NFS shares which are defined in `/etc/exports`.

When `exportfs -r` is ran all the ZFS managed shares drop--`zfs get sharenfs tank/set` still shows the property is set, but until I reset the property via `zfs set sharenfs=...` the share can't be mounted by the client.

Is there a way to prevent `exportfs -r` from killing ZFS managed shares, or a way of updating non-ZFS shares without interfering with ZFS shares?  As a last resort is there a quick and easy way to have ZFS re-set all sharenfs properties?

Answer (score 1):

Use one or the other.

I suggest using `/etc/exports` for consistency and readability, *especially* if your NFS server is serving data from non-ZFS filesystems.